# How to restrict user login for specific IP-address (private address)?

Tags: configuration, sshd, access-control

I have two users on my ssh-server machine, user_A and user_B. user_B is permitted to log  in with private key only for security reasons, because he needs to log in from remote. All this works.
My problem: How do I prevent user_A to login likewise from remote with username/password, because he only needs to login from the local network?
According to the man page of sshd, CIDR-notation is allowed.

What I have done:
#605433 suggests
`AllowUsers my_login@123.45.67.89`, so I adapted to `AllowUsers user_A@192.168.10.0/24`

#740700 suggests:

```
Match 192.168.0.10/24
   AllowGroups PrivateSubnetSshUsers
```

My version looks like

```
Match 192.168.10.0/24
   AllowUsers user_A
```

Against my expectations, user_A can still log in from 192.168.1.220 in both cases.
I had done some `systemctl restart sshd` before retrying.

What do I overlook here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there is error in your `Match` statement as it should be `Match address 192.168.10.0/24` and not just `Match 192.168.10.0/24`. Your version gives an error message when trying to restart sshd. Didn't you get one?

Second, you should `Match` on user name, not on address. The following should work:

```
Match user user_A
   AllowUsers user_A@192.168.10.0/24
```

BTW. From my tests, `AllowUsers user_A@192.168.10.0/24` alone (ie. not in `Match` block) also works (so you must have done something wrong when testing it), but it restricts **all other users** except user_A from login **at all** (and user_A can login only from the specified network). If it is within a `Match` block as above, then user_A can login only from specified network, and all other users can login from any IP address.

Comment: I had checked sshd restarting in auth.log. No error messages. Now it looks like 
`Match user user_A
   AllowUsers user_A@192.168.2.0/24`
After sshd restart (checked!) user_A can still log in. The 192.168.2.0/24 does not exist here.
`Aug 30 16:09:08 Myhost sshd[22781]: Accepted password for user_A from 192.168.1.91 port 36776 ssh2`

Comment: I have tested my answer on my server and it works. Do you have any other `AllowUsers` or `AllowGroups` directives in your sshd configuration that may conflict with this? And what is your sshd version?

Answer (score 0):

According to the manual (https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sshd_config.5.html), it should work like this:

```
# Only user_B is allowed to login
AllowUsers user_B

# Only the group PrivateSubnetSshUsers is allowed to login from the network 192.168.10.0/24
Match Address 192.168.10.0/24
        AllowGroups PrivateSubnetSshUsers 

# user_B is not allowed to login with password
Match User user_B
        PasswordAuthentication no
```

With the first option you lock out all users except of the user_B.
The second option allows a login if you connect from the given network and are member of the group PrivateSubnetSshUsers.
The third option force user_B to use keys.

It is not super straight forward, but it should do the job.

Comment: This is something logically different from what the OP requested. In your example, only the group PrivateSubnetSshUsers is allowed to login from 192.168.10.0/24, so noone else is allowed to login from this network - but the group PrivateSubnetSshUsers is allowed to login also from outside that network.
The OP wants the group to be able to login **only from the specified network** and from nowhere else.

Comment: Yes, raj, that's not my problem, since I had created user_B without password from the start, so that I didn't have to do the second part of the answer above. My problem is about user_A who can still log in from seemingly anywhere; contrary to what I read from said cited manual.

Comment: OK, I edited the config.
Now just user_B can login, but just without password. If you are coming from the internal network also the users from the group PrivateSubnetSshUsers are allowed to login.
Hopefully I understand everything right :)

Answer (score 0):

I am utmost embarrassed. Of course.the case is solved, like raj had correctly indicated.
My fault, and therefore embarrassment, was to always edit ssh_config, and not sshd_config.
My apologies, and thanks again for your help!